# iPhone: error: request for member 'table' in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, hierarchy

When it comes to compiling my application, I get the error mentioned in the title. How would I go about remedying this error? Basically, I want to get from one table to the other. Hierarchy, navigation.

**NextViewController.m**

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "NextViewController.h"


@implementation NextViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction) changeTable:(NSString *)str{
    tblCSS.table = str;
}
```

The last line contains the error.

If you need any more code, just ask. I'll amend this post with it.

Cheers,
Jack

**NextViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface NextViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblCSS;
}

- (IBAction) changeTable:(NSString *)str;
@end
```

Comment: You need to post the code for the header (.h file) that defines `tblCSS`. That is where your problem lays.

Comment: UITableView doesn't have a `table` property. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your tblCSS variable is an object, and it doesn't have a property called table.  You should either create it as a property, or create accessor variables for it.

**Edit:**

It's not clear what your code is trying to do.  `tblCSS` is a `UITableView`, which doesn't have a property called `table`; and if it did, it is unlikely that it would be a `NSString` (but who knows?).

Also, `IBAction`s typically take `sender` as an argument, which will usually be a `UIControl`, not a `NSString`.

Comment: Could you expand on that? I'm quite new to Objective-C and I'm not entirely familiar with it's terminology.

Comment: It would be simplest if you posted your definition for tblCSS and table.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how I should set a new property called table? Thank you.

Comment: You need to figure out what you are trying to do, first.

Comment: The aim is to change the visible view on the stack to another table, in this case, tblCSS. I think I've done everything else right, it's just this, really.